# Laravel hasmany relationship with withCount()

Tags: laravel, relationships

Trying to display the count of the users table that belong to the company table I only get NULL while I can normally see the correct results while calling the relationship directly. Here is the display code:

```
@foreach($allCompanies as $theCompany)
{{ $theCompany->getUser_count }}
@endforeach
```

Here is the model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Companies extends Model {
    protected $table = 'companies'; 

    public function getUser(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\User', 'company_id');
    }
}
```

and here is the controller:

```
$allCompanies   = Companies::withCount('getUser')->get();
```

When I call $theCompany->getUser, I get a json of users but withCount returns always NULL.

Comment: What does `{{ $theCompany->getUser_count }}` show?

Comment: Nothing. Its empty. Var_Dump says NULL

Comment: Have you defined `getUser_count`? Shouldn't it be `getUser->count()` instead, if `getUser` returns a collection?

Comment: please show what  dd($allCompanies) gives

Comment: What's the result of `dd($theCompany->getAttributes())`?

Comment: @Sohel0415  Thanks it looks like laravel decided to change the name of the field that was saving the count in? Instead of $theCompany->getUser_count it returned $theCompany->get_user_count. Anyone knows why is that?

Comment: I think its laravel naming conventions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `underscore` in variable name instead of `camelCase`.

```
@foreach($allCompanies as $theCompany)
    {{ $theCompany->get_user_count }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks that is correct but can you explain why the docs are wrong? According to them the new field generated by laravel would be $theCompany->getUser_count and not $theCompany->get_user_count. Maybe laravel is that smart that understands that a capitalized letter means a new word so it breaks it there? Impressive

Comment: doc is correct I think but it could have given an example when relationship is in camelcase name which is absent there

Answer (score 0):

Change the code

```
$allCompanies   = Companies::withCount('getUser')->get();
```

To

```
$allCompanies   = Companies::with ('getUser')->withCount('getUser')->get();
```